# Tags are automatically converted if they match post names. Stop It!

Tags: pages, tags, updates

Recently I noticed that if I had post tags that are the same as a page name, wordpress is updating the tag to the page title rather than the slug entered. So in this case if I give wordpress the tag `'adventure-training'` it is updated to `'Adventure Training'` similar to the name of a page on the site.

How do I stop that from happening.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Comment: You got any plugins installed? What version you running? I just tried this on a vanilla install of 3.1 and was unable to replicate the problem.

Comment: No plugin that has anything to do with tags or SEO also 3.1

Comment: I honestly can't replicate this. Regardless if a plugin is to do with SEO or tags, disable ALL of them, then confirm the issue still persists.

Comment: confirmed still happening. More inexplicably this only happens with 'Adventure-Training' the next tag is the same as the page Master Scuba Diver, yet displays perfectly normally as 'master-scuba-diver' What the hell is going on!

Comment: Do you have a term with the same name in a different taxonomy? Or as a category?

Comment: @Robin I Knight - I too don't see this happening. Are you adding the tag via the admin interface or via PHP code? P.S. You might want to pull back on the *"Marvellous"* bit; if not the signature nazis here on StackExchange may do it for you *(I'm a mod I am go slapped for adding "Hope this helps" to all my answers.)*

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by editing the post tag itself inside the tags section of the admin page. Thanks for all help.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting this in your functions.php:

`remove_filter('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');`

I found when writing another function that it was "helpfully" redirecting urls like that for me. This will disable that.